# Posting in Facebook Page wall from a PHP application

Tags: php, facebook

```
<? php

   require_once "src/facebook.php";

   $appId = "********" ;
   $secret = "*************" ;
   $returnurl = "*******************";
   $permissions = "manage_page,publish_stream" ;

   $fb = new Facebook(array ('appId' => $appId , 'secret' => $secret)) ;

   $fbuser = $fb->getUser();

   if($fbuser){

if(isset($_post['msg']) and $_post['msg']!=''){
    try{
        $message = array(
            'message' => $_POST['msg']

        );
        $url = '/'.$_POST['pageid'].'/feed';
        $result = $fb =>api($url.'POST',$message);
        if($result){
            echo "The data posted on facebook wall!!";

        }

    }catch (FacebookApiException $error){

        echo $error=>getMessage();
    }   

}

try{
    $qry = 'select page_id, name from page where page_id in (select page_id from page_admin where uid = '.fbuser.')';

    $pages = $fb=>api(array('method'=>'fql.query','query'=>$qry));

    if(empty($pages)){
        echo "Sorry,the user docs not have any page to post.";

    }else{
        echo '

            <form action="" method="post">
            page : <select name="pageid">';     
            foreach ($pages as $page){

                echo '<option value="'.$pages['page_id'].'">'.$page['name'].'</option>';
            }
        echo    '</select><br/>
            Message : <textarea name="msg"></textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="post to facebook"/>
            </form>
        ';
    }

}catch (FacebookApiException $error){

    echo $error=>getMessage();
}   
     }else{

     $loginurl = $fb->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>$permission , 'redirect-   url'=>$returnurl));

    echo '<a href="'.$loginurl.'">Login with Facebook</a>' ;

   }


    ?>
```

That's my code that's having a problem.
Here's the error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_REQUIRE_ONCE in /home/u383853101/public_html/index.php on line 3

Please help guys, I'm not able to find the solution for this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space from betwen `<?` and `php` , It should be just `<?php`

Answer (score 0):

Fix is below.

You write require_once('..') like this. Don't forget the brackets. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).

Also, the php tag should be `<?php` instead of `<? php`.

```
   require_once('src/facebook.php');
```

Comment: I try this also but not worth.

Comment: What is the exact error now, is it the same? Can you please try it again, using ' ' instead of " ".